# jQuery select elements that do not contain a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I would like to select all elements with the `.hi` class, that do **not** contain the `.image` class.

```
<div class="hi">
  <div class="hue">
    <div class="image">
       456
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hi">
  <div class="hue">
    <div class="image">
        123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hi">
  <div class="hue">
    here
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
console.log($('.hi').find('.hue > :not(.image')));
```

Comment: There are a few problems with the code you wrote (missing `)` before the closing `'`, for example). But to answer your question, this is a pure css selector that should work `.hue > *:not(.image)`. The `*` selects all elements, and the `:not` qualifies it

Comment: Is it part of your requirement that the `.hue` element **must** be a child (not just any descendant) of the `.hi` element? If so, the linked question's answers address it. If not, that's not the right duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do it just with a selector, you'd use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) with [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$(".hi:not(:has(.image))")
// or to be more specific:
$(".hi:not(:has(.hue > .image))")
```

Note that `:has` is jQuery-specific.

To do it with `filter`, you could use `find` in the callback:

```
$(".hi").filter(function() { return $(this).find(".image").length == 0; })
// or to be more specific:
$(".hi").filter(function() { return $(this).find(".hue > .image").length == 0; })
```